# Problem rebinding isearch key in Emacs

Tags: shortcut-keys, emacs

Hello I am trying to rebind the Emacs key for isearch (C-s) to the more CUA like C-i becuase C-s is bound to save. I did the following:

```
(global-set-key "\C-i" 'isearch-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-i") 'isearch-backward)
```

which works fine until I try to find the next match. The problem is that in Emacs this is carrried out by typing C-s again. Unfortunately I cannot bind the isearch-repeat-forward commands to C-i because that undoes the binding of C-i to isearch-forward.

I perhps wouldnt mind something like C-r for repeat but annoyingly emacs has a different repeat command for forward and reverse incremental search

Does anyone know of a good fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isearch-repeat-forward` is bound to <kbd>C-s</kbd> on the *Isearch mode*. You may notice that when you press <kbd>C-s</kbd> you enter a new minor mode in your buffer. Since each mode has its own keybinding map, you should alter <kbd>C-s</kbd> binding on this map. The `define-key` function receives an argument which is the mode map you want to bind the key, in that case `isearch-mode`. Try put this on your `init.el`

```lisp
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-i") 'isearch-repeat-forward)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-S-i") 'isearch-repeat-backward)
```